# how to access model or view variable in angular 4 for two way data binding

Tags: angular, angular4-forms

I want to access value of textarea in component class through button click function triggered through button click.
**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-12">

        <textarea class="form-control" placeholder="Add Comment">
         {{comment}}
        </textarea>
      <button (click)="addComment($event, comment)" style="margin-top: 2%" class="btn-success">Add Comment</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**component:**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-add-comments',
  templateUrl: './add-comments.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./add-comments.component.css']
})
export class AddCommentsComponent implements OnInit {

  comment:string = "Hellooooo";


  //commentsArr: commentsArr[];

  addComment(event, comment);

  addComment(event, comment)
  {
    console.log(this.comment);


  }

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

I want to to access comment inside comment data inside comment component.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**there is no scope variable in Angular 2+.**

In Angular 2+ there is NgModel which helps you with two way binding.

https://angular.io/api/forms/NgModel

To access value of text area in your component.

In html

```
<textarea class="form-control" [(NgModel)]=comment placeholder="Add Comment">
<input type="button" value="Add" (click)="AddComment()" />
```

In component:

```
comment:any="";

AddComment(){

console.log(this.comment);
}
```

Here comment var will always be mapped to inputs in textarea.

Answer (score 1):

You should use property biding on the textarea instead of using the `comment` directly. An example:

```
<form (ngSubmit)="formHandler()" #form="ngForm">
    <textarea 
      name="your-name"
      [(ngModel)]="comment">
    </textarea>
    <button (click)="addComment()">
</form>
```

Then on the `addComment()` access the value of it using `this.comment`. The `ngModel` will update the value of the property `comment` automatically as the user types inside the textarea.

Answer (score 1):

**Approach 1**

You can make the input field as template variable like `#comment` and can pass value to the method on click.
e.g

```
<input type="text" #comment>
<button (click)="addComment(#comment.value)">Add Comment</button>
```

your `addComment` method will be

```
addComment(comment){
console.log(comment)
}
```

Your code will be

```
<div class="container">
      <div class="row">       
 <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-12">
            <textarea #comment class="form-control" placeholder="Add Comment">
             {{comment}}
            </textarea>
          <button (click)="addComment(comment.value)" style="margin-top: 2%" class="btn-success">Add Comment</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

**addComment**

```
addComment(comment)
  {
    console.log(comment);
  }
```

**Approach 2**

as shared by @Treeindev

```
<form (ngSubmit)="formHandler()" #form="ngForm">
    <textarea 
      name="your-name"
      [(ngModel)]="comment">
    </textarea>
    <button (click)="addComment()">
</form>
```

**Approach 3**

shared by @Dheeraj Kumar

```
<textarea class="form-control" [(NgModel)]=comment placeholder="Add Comment">
<input type="button" value="Add" (click)="AddComment()" />

comment:any="";

AddComment(){

console.log(this.comment);
}
```

Comment: @Simer Mark the answer if we helped.

Answer (score 1):

**You can try this**

HTML:

```
<textarea [(ngModel)]='myText'></textarea>
<button (click)="doSomething()">Click</button>
```

TS:

```
doSomething(){
   console.log(this.myText);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use two way binding or @ViewChild to get the reference of element from the template.

[Live Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-av2hdy)

TS :

```js
import { Component, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  comment:string = "Hellooooo";
  @ViewChild('textAreaRef') myLocalRef; //Here we create a marker in the element and refer the element using @ViewChild and assigning it to myLocalRef
  addComment()
  {
    console.log(this.myLocalRef.nativeElement.value);
  }
}
```

Template :

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12">
      <textarea 
        class="form-control" 
        placeholder="Add Comment"
        #textAreaRef>
        {{comment}}
      </textarea>
      <hr>
      <button (click)="addComment()" style="margin-top: 2%" class="btn-success">Add Comment</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
From Angular 2+ the support of $scope has been removed, so when you want to access an element defined on a template into the TS file, this can be done in 3 ways:

 1. Local Reference
 2. @ViewChild
 3. Two-way binding

When you just want to pass the value on some action without binding then #1 and #2 is the option, or we can define a variable in TS file and bind it to an element in the template file using two-binding.

    enter code here

**1. Example using Local Reference:**
**Template:**
 <textarea #textAreaRef>{{comment}}</textarea>
 <button (click)="addComment(textAreaRef)">Add Comment</button>

**TS:**
 addComment(value:HTMLTextAreaElement)
  {
    console.log(value);
  }

**2. Example using @ViewChild and Local Reference:**
**Template:**
 <textarea #textAreaRef>{{comment}}</textarea>
 <button (click)="addComment()">Add Comment</button>

**TS:**
@ViewChild('textAreaRef') referenceEl: ElementRef;
 addComment()
  {
    console.log(referenceEl.nativeElement.value);
  }
Here we don't need to pass the local reference on button click.

**3. Example using Two-way data binding:**
**Template:**
 <textarea [(ngModel)]='comments'>{{comments}}</textarea>
 <button (click)="addComment()">Add Comment</button>

**TS:**
comments: string = "";

 addComment()
  {
    console.log(this.comments);
  }
```