# Angular. Get "ngModel" reference from another component

Tags: angular

I have a component which contains ng-select. So i'm using this component in another component. How can i get ng-select's "ngModel" reference from second component?

```html
template: `<ng-select 
                      [items]="divisions"
                      bindLabel="name"
                      bindValue="id"
                      [disabled]="disabled"
                      [(ngModel)]="selectedDivision"
                      #divisionControl="ngModel"
                      placeholder={{emptyText}}                    
                      [required]="required"
                      (change)="ngModelChanged()">
          </ng-select>`
```

I want to get

> #divisionControl

reference from another component. Anyone can help me?

Comment: Please read: https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction#parent-and-children-communicate-using-a-service

Comment: You can start by checking the [ngmodel documentation](https://angular.io/api/forms/NgModel), or [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49670896/how-to-access-model-or-view-variable-in-angular-4-for-two-way-data-binding)